# subpanel is not calling view.edit.php sugarcrm

Tags: php, sugarcrm

http://urdhva-tech.blogspot.in/2013/02/mark-field-required-conditionally.html

I have used this code...in custom/modules/'modulename'/views/view.edit.php...but when I used custom module as a subpanel view.edit.php is not called.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be called in subpanels, you'll need to copy your customization to one or two more views, I believe it's view.quickcreate.php -- in some versions of Sugar there is also a separate view.quickedit.php. I've found subpanel view extensions to be a relatively dynamic bit of the Sugar system because it's changed several times between 6.4 and 6.7.